# Why writeValue called after detroy component which implements ControlValueAccessor?

Tags: angular, forms, form-control, controlvalueaccessor

I have implemented ControlValueAccessor in my own primitive component. Its code you see:  [there (plunker)](https://embed.plnkr.co/ITd7ZZlTandD2NPJhkBb/)

In parent component, I use my  with ng-if directive. I can hide and show my component through checkbox. Component inits and destroys each times but writeValue function call a lot of times. Please check my code at plunker

Why is this happening? How I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to recreate the control:

```
  resetValue() {
    this.name = new FormControl('initial');
    this.name.setValue('has been reset');
  }
```

As @Сергей mentioned the reason is because every time when ControlValueAccessor component created, it register its callback functions in private property of formControl (for example, _onChange). This is array, which accumulate these functions. One of the solutions is creating new FormControl.

Comment: Thank you. I solved this problem already. And I want to write why this is happening. Every time when ControlValueAccessor component created, it register its callback functions in private property of formControl (for example, _onChange). This is array, which accumulate these functions. One of the solutions is creating new FormControl.